# Kernelization algorithm for the following problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parameterized-complexity, vertex-cover

We are given an undirected graph $ G $ and a positive parameter
$ k \geq 0 $. The problem is to decide if there exists a set $ S \subseteq V(G) $ of size at most $ k $ such that $ G − S $ does not have any path on three vertices.

Is there any deterministic kernel algorithm for this problem with $ \Theta (k^2) $ vertices?

**Kernelization algorithm definition**: Given $ (G,k) $, output an equivalent instance $ (G’,k’) $ of the same problem in polynomial time, such that $ |G’| \leq f(k) $ and $ k’ \leq k $.

Comment: Does "$G-S$ does not have any path on three vertices" mean that each connected component of $G-S$ is of size at most $2$?

Comment: Probably, although it's not completely obvious. If it's as you say, then the problem is the same as the 1-BDD problem posted about the other day (bounded degree deletion).

Comment: Do you mean induced paths of length three, or any paths at all on three vertices, i.e., that every connected component has size at most two?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be stated as $3$-path vertex cover problem. A simple google search gives [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.07022.pdf) paper. The authors design a kernel of size $5k$ for this problem.

Comment: I think there was misunderstanding, I mean to $ \Theta (k^2) $ vertices.

Comment: @John19 A kernel of $5k$ vertices is also a kernel of $O(k^2)$ vertices. So what is the issue here?

Comment: @John19 If you want to make it $\Omega(k^2)$, you can always stop the algorithm when $\Theta(k^2)$ vertices are reached